# Firefox opens *.bz2 in GIMP

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, firefox, mime-types

Firefox tries to open downloaded `*.bz2` archives in GIMP even though both `xdg-open` and `nautilus` open it with `file-roller` as intended. This only happens when clicking on the downward arrow next to the search bar and then clicking on the file, using Tools->Downloads from the menu works as intended.

```
$ xdg-mime query default application/x-bzip
org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop
```

In `nautilus`, "Open With" on the file also correctly shows "Archive Manager" as default application.
Edit->Preferences->Applications is set to "always ask" for "Bzip archive" (setting it to Archive Manager doesn't help as well).

**How can I get Firefox to open `*.bz2` files with file-roller when clicking on the downward-arrow next to the search bar and then on the downloaded file?**

Versions: Arch Linux 4.6.4-1, GNOME Shell 3.20.3, Firefox 47.0.1, Gimp 2.8.

**Output of** `grep -e "bzip\|bz2" -C1 .mozilla/firefox/[ProfileFolder]/mimeTypes.rdf:`

```
 <RDF:Description RDF:about="urn:mimetype:application/x-bzip2"
                   NC:value="application/x-bzip2"
                   NC:editable="true"
                   NC:description="Bzip-Archiv">
    <NC:fileExtensions>bz2</NC:fileExtensions>
    <NC:fileExtensions>boz</NC:fileExtensions>
    <NC:handlerProp RDF:resource="urn:mimetype:handler:application/x-bzip2"/>
    <NC:possibleApplication RDF:resource="urn:handler:local:/usr/bin/file-roller"/>
--
    <RDF:li RDF:resource="urn:mimetype:text/plain"/>
    <RDF:li RDF:resource="urn:mimetype:application/x-bzip2"/>
    <RDF:li RDF:resource="urn:mimetype:audio/mpeg"/>
--
  </RDF:Description>
  <RDF:Description RDF:about="urn:mimetype:handler:application/x-bzip2"
                   NC:useSystemDefault="true"
```

Comment: Does `mimeopen` also start file-roller on bz2 files?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I don't have `mimeopen` on my system.

Answer (score 2):

In your firefox profile folder (normally something like `~/.mozilla/firefox/[......].profile`), there is a file named `mimeTypes.rdf`.  Open it with your favourite editor and edit it to achieve the desired behavior.

Such an addition could look liek this:

1. search for a line with an opening `<RDF:Description RDF:about="urn:mimetype:handler:application/x-bzip2"` tag as content.
2. Be aware that such a line can occur multiple times in the file and pick the one which encloses a `<NC:possibleApplication RDF:resource="urn:handler:[....]"/>` tag
3. Edit this tag to not from something like
   `<NC:possibleApplication RDF:resource="urn:handler:local:/usr/bin/gimp"/>` to `<NC:possibleApplication RDF:resource="urn:handler:local:/usr/bin/file-roller"/>`
4. Restart firefox and test
5. If necessary adjust `mimeTypes.rdf` file further

It might be good to backup the file to be on the safe side

Comment: There was only one mention of gimp, connected to JPEG images and not to bzip2, which I deleted to be sure but the problem persists.

Comment: @KonradHöffner My guess than is that gimp is not explicitly set in a `<NC: possibleApplication ....` tag but results to be run as sort of a default application (i.e. it would have a bz2 related tag setting ` NC:useSystemDefault="true"` which should be changed then)..... To achieve the desired behavior open bz2 with `file-roller` it should suffice to add the `<NC:possibleApplication RDF:resource="urn:handler:local:/usr/bin/file-roller"/>` in the last tag you find for `<RDF:Description RDF:about="urn:mimetype:handler:application/x-bzip2"`.

Comment: Even that didn't help :-(

Comment: maybe could you add to your question the output of `grep -e "bzip\|bz2" -C1 .mozilla/firefox/[yourProfileFolder]/mimeTypes.rdf` which should allow to have a look to the file and tailer the answer patter. Alternatively look at http://kb.mozillazine.org/MimeTypes.rdf as this should document the feature you require.

Comment: Sure! I added it to the question.

Comment: @KonradHöffner as you can see in the output you have added to your question the last line read `<RDF:Description RDF:about="urn:mimetype:handler:application/x-bzip2"
                   NC:useSystemDefault="true"` which is something you might want to change to `<RDF:Description RDF:about="urn:mimetype:handler:application/x-bzip2"
                   NC:useSystemDefault="false"`
Also you then might want to add the line `<NC:possibleApplication RDF:resource="urn:handler:local:/usr/bin/file-roller"/>` inside the last tag. Just to be on the safe side also check what `which file-roller` yields

Answer (score 0):

Firefox also reads `~/.config/mimeapps.list` (on Xubuntu 16.04 at least, might be in `~/.local/share/applications` on Arch?).

I had `application/octet-stream=gimp.desktop` under `[Default Applications]` (and `application/octet-stream=gimp.desktop;zathura.desktop;…` under `[Added Associations]`). Downloads are often served with bad mime types, giving "octet-stream", so you'll actually have to check under Network in the Firefox console for what mime type you're getting.

Putting `file-roller.desktop` as the Default entry in that file improved life for me. You can also do it with this command:

```
xdg-mime default file-roller.desktop application/octet-stream
```

Comment: commenting out the line `application/octet-stream` entirely (add a semicolon in front) seems to solve the problem completely (maybe it falls back to reading the extension) and firefox opens stuff with the correct applications again.